# Need to match the format below

Tags: python, format

Need to match the format below:

```
0: F - 37
1: F - 37

for each in phred_score:
    i += 1
    print(i, ":", each, "-", convert_phred(each))

print(convert_phred(each))
```

Expected format:

```
0 : F - 37
1 : F - 37
```

I want to print the ":" right off of the value (i) without any space but don't know how to tag a colon next to a variable. Any help would be much appreciated!

Python 3

Comment: Try it using [regex](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm).

Comment: you can simply use concatenation instead of using multiple print arguments. So just `print(str(i)+":",each,...`

Comment: thank you...very new to this

Comment: Do not get into the habit of string concatenation. The correct way to do this in modern Python is using the format method. If you are on version 3.6 or greater, use the new f-string syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment,

You can use concatenation instead of relying on multiple print arguments.

e.g. `print(str(i) + ":", each, ...)`

You can also use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 0):

To format your output you can use a [format string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) like this:

```
for i, each in enumerate(phred_score):
    print("{i} : {each} - {result}".format(i=i, each=each, result=convert_phred(each)))
```

Notice: I simplify your code by using the `enumerate` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting option available in python. A simple introduction is available here https://pyformat.info/

```
0: F - 37
1: F - 37

for each in phred_score:
    i += 1
    print("{0}: {1} - {2}".format(i,each,convert_phred(each)))
    #print(i, ":", each, "-", convert_phred(each))

print(convert_phred(each))
```